# React checkbutton onChange event returns synthetic event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React checkbox component. I'm trying to change the state on every click and run a function based on the previous state. On the React everytime I click on the button I'm trying to return event to my console.log function in the index.js.

But it's always returning synthetic event and I can't reach the event.target.value.

My index.js and props are;

```
ReactDOM.render(<ReactCheckBox
    isChecked={false}
    textCheck="Checked"
    textUncheck="Checked"
    onCheckedRun={event => console.log(event.target)}
    onUncheckedRun={event => console.log(event.target)}
    buttonPosition="right"
/>, document.getElementById('myCheckBox'))
```

and my ReactCheckBox component is;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ReactCheckBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            checked: ""
        }
        this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            checked: this.props.isChecked
        })
    }

    onChangeHandler(event) {
        this.setState(function (previousState, props) {
            console.log('State: ',this.state.checked)
            if (previousState.checked === true) {
                props.onCheckedRun(event)
            } else {
                props.onUncheckedRun(event)
            }
            return {
                checked: !this.state.checked
            }
        }
        )
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.disabled === "true") {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                            <div className="uniform-checker border-primary-600 text-primary-800">
                                <span className="checked">
                                    <input onChange={this.onChangeHandler} type="checkbox" className="form-check-input-styled-primary" defaultChecked={this.state.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'} data-fouc="" disabled></input>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            Primary checkbox
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div className="form-check">
                            <label className="form-check-label">
                                <div className="uniform-checker border-primary-600 text-primary-800">
                                    <span className={this.state.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}>
                                        <input onChange={this.onChangeHandler} type="checkbox" className="form-check-input-styled-primary" defaultChecked={this.state.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'} ></input>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                Primary checkbox
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

export default ReactCheckBox
```

Has anyone had the same issue ? How can I over come synthetic event and get the real event so I can reach value of it ?

**UPDATE**

**Synthetic error event**

> index.js:1375 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance
>   reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method
>   `currentTarget` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a
>   no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around,
>   use event.persist(). See fb.me/react-event-pooling for more
>   information.

Comment: You may want to look [here](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/#Checkboxes.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `event.target` try `event.currentTarget` to get the specific targeted element.

- [event.currentTarget docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- [a nice post about event.target vs event.currentTarget](https://medium.com/@florenceliang/javascript-event-delegation-and-event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-c9680c3a46d1)

**Update:**
In relation to your update and the error, can you try doing this:
instead of using `<input onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>` do this:

```
<input onChange={(e)=>{this.onChangeHandler(e)}}>
```

or just:

```
<input onChange={(e)=>{onchangeHandler(e)}}>
```

So the full line would be:

```
<input onChange={()=>{this.onChangeHandler(e)}} type="checkbox" className="form-check-input-styled-primary" defaultChecked={this.state.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'} ></input>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I've learned something but I'm still getting the same error. I've added the error please see updated question.

Comment: @Capan ok check out my update. I think you are never actually passing the event itself so one of the fixes should solve that and pass down the proper event. Let me know if it works.

Comment: problem still continues  @aviya.developer

Answer (score 5):

Try to do it:

```
<input onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result, Yoy May try This .

```
console.log(event.currentTarget.checked);
```

it will return true  or false

no Neeed to do

```
<input onChange={(e)=>{onchangeHandler(e)}}>
```

**UPDATE**

Synthetic error event

> index.js:1375 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance
>   reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method 
>   currentTarget on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op
>   function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use
>   event.persist(). See fb.me/react-event-pooling for more information.

simple just call.

```
 onChangeHandler(event) {
    event.persist();
    this.setState(function(previousState, props) {
      console.log("State: ", this.state.checked);
      if (previousState.checked === true) {
        props.onCheckedRun(event.currentTarget.checked);
      } else {
        props.onUncheckedRun(event.currentTarget.checked);
      }
      return {
        checked: !this.state.checked
      };
    });   }
```

Comment: Well I've tried your solution I'm still having the same issue. event.currentTarget.value returns an undefined value

Comment: checkbox never give u `event.currentTarget.checked` . It return only checked or unchecked state as boolean. `event.currentTarget.checked` will true or false. @capan